# Accept Rate - Closed and "No Answer" questions should not count

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, closed-questions, accept-rate

I really like the "Accept Rate" feature.  I think it will encourage folks to accept answers once they get a good one (though, hopefully they will not accept bad ones just to get their rate up).

I have a concern about this though,  I have several questions that no one ever posted an answer for.  I also have a few that were closed before I could accept an answer.

Questions like these that are not "acceptable" should not count towards my percentage.

I also think, though on a lesser level of importance, that any question with only negatively scored answers should not count towards your accept rate.  (Sometimes people throw out crap answers just hoping to get an up vote or an lucky guess.)

Comment: @Bolt what has been completed?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: This "feature request" was for something that was already in place, so it's [status-completed] in a way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the case, from the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/):

- Questions must not be community wiki.
- Questions must not be closed.
- Questions must be more than 3 days old.
- Questions must have at least 1 answer.
- There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.

Comment: Hmmmm, it did not calculate out like this for me. Maybe I am just bad at math.....

Comment: Ahh, the comments from the blog post indicate that the value is heavily cached.  I had 90% and then accepted a two answers and it did not update, so I assumed that I had enough questions that two accepted answers did not make a difference in the percentage.  This also lead to the the above question (Most of may remaining answers fit in the categories in this question).

Comment: You won't see any changes until cache refreshes. This could be up to a couple hours often times.

Comment: I have a 92% accept rate on superuser. Reason: 1 question with no answers. How can I accept something that has no answers in the first place?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/31568 I believe is the question that you have not accepted an answer for and is counting against your percentage. It has 2 answers and is more than 3 days old. Additionally, while having a 100% accept rate might be "nice", it is not important, 92% is more than acceptable and shouldn't stretch to accept a bad answer just to get to 100%.

Comment: I think there is a bug in the code determining if a question has a least 1 answer. My current accept rate on SO i 10 out of 11. I only have one unanswered question, but that question has no answers.

Comment: @Jan, this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323367) question has answers, but no accepted answer. Make sure you click to the second page of the questions you've asked to see them all.