# Accept Rate - how to keep it at 100%?

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

My accept rate is 89%, even though I have gone to my profile page and viewed all questions I have asked, and each one has been given an answer.

What do I have to do in the future or now to prevent my accept rate from going down, and how can I get it back up to 100%?

Comment: Once you get to 75%, you have my blessing to flag every comment that mentions your accept rate as spam/noise. I'll back you up every time I see one in the queue. **Don't worry about keeping it at 100%** unless you really, really want to.

Comment: Every time I see someone with a mid range accept rate (> ~55%), I know that person knows how to accept answers and knows what it does and doesn't need me auto commenting. Just accept the answers that have helped you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must *accept* an answer (click the checkmark) on [each *eligible* question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16902/accept-rate-closed-and-no-answer-questions-should-not-count/16906#16906):

> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days old.
> - Questions must have at least 1 answer.
> - There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.

Specifically [this post of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435529/mvc-url-helper-method-for-static-pages) of yours has an answer and is over 3 days old but you haven't accepted it.

As [mentioned elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24130/show-not-only-accept-rate-but-also-number-of-questions-asked/24133#24133), hovering over the "86% accept rate" text will inform you how many questions are considered eligible.  For you, at this moment, it says "this user has accepted an answer for 6 of 7 eligible questions."  The one above is the one you need to accept to bring it to 100%.

That being said, if it *isn't answered correctly*, I wouldn't worry about it.  I *would*, however, work to gain enough rep to [offer a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) to bring better answers to your question.

---

See also:

- [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/16729#16729)
- [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: +1 for "I would't worry about it." I believe >70% is considered good.

Comment: I love how I asked a question about non accepted question answers, and took 5 years to accept the answer to the question. Definitely Meta... and Lazy.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents: in case you ask a question, get answers and none is satisfying **don't delete the question** just to maintain 100% accept rate. If you find the solution yourself, post it as answer and Accept it otherwise if some answer did help (even though not perfect) accept it and worst case start a bounty to draw more answers - if even this fails I think that after a week you can post answer explaining the situation and accept it.

Comment: Also: It's semi-acceptable to post a faux answer yourself, marking it community wiki, summarizing the current efforts/research, but clearly state it as "temporarily accepted". That way you can later switch the tick mark, and delete this community wiki placeholder answer. That's a workaround to retain the magical 100% accept rate.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that you've "accepted" an answer for every eligible question; for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435529/mvc-url-helper-method-for-static-pages).

By "accepted" the system means that you've clicked the check mark to set an accepted answer.

Comment: you can click those check marks? well... you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing accept rate to 100% is not necessary. There is some global pressure for accepting answers which is partially good but partially bad because if no answer provide a solution to your question there is no reason to accept any of them just to make your accept rate 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Each one has been given an answer, but you didn't accept one for each. You can tell whether you've accepted answer by the color of the number of answers: If the number is gold, there is an accepted answer, if it is white, there isn't. If you look at your questions page, there are two questions, which you didn't accept an answer to.