# It's raining badges

Tags: support, badges

I just got 4 badges in the last few hours, but none of the votes happened in that timeframe.  Did the [badge award mechanic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96779/badge-behavior-how-should-awarding-work) that was being talked about happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes indeed, [this went live tonight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96779/badge-behavior-how-should-awarding-work) as part of a major code-side overhaul of badges, enjoy those missing badges now being granted.