# Badges are not removed on roll back

Tags: support, badges, rollbacks

On roll back, badges awarded during this period are not removed.

Suppose I earned `Nice Question` badge for my question. But after roll back votes to the question became less than 10, then also `Nice Question` badge was not removed. Is it a bug?

Comment: But I got next time too..

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - That's outdated information, the badges are no longer "count based" as of months ago, several meta answers around with that info.

Comment: @Nick didn't know that.. any official post about it?

Comment: @Sha - I've answered it several times, I guess that counts?  I did a major badge code overhaul on the backend months ago to make them more maintainable, but ended up fixing tons of bugs and moving them off count-based in cases with a reason as well.

Comment: Actually what I said before is not relevant - Nice Question badge is granted once the question reach +10 score it doesn't matter if later the score goes down - the badge is still valid, and it's per question.

Comment: For those interested - [here is the change Nick was talking about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96779/badge-behavior-how-should-awarding-work).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a bug, this is by design.

Badges are not removed (apart from tag badges).