# Is it possible to request a badge recalc?

Tags: feature-request, support, badges, serial-voting

Somebody was stalking me yesterday on Stack Overflow, they upvoted 20 of my answers that already had 9 votes each. This, in turn, lead to me receiving 20 Nice Answer badges and 10 Enlightened badges.  As I expected, the rep was reversed this morning. <strike>The only problem is, the badges remain, which means that any Nice Answer or Enlightened badges I earn genuinely, up to those amounts, will not be counted.</strike>

I'd certainly prefer it if my badges were properly synced, is it possible to request a badge recalc? Can a diamond mod do it?

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)I propose this should be done automatically for vote-related badges when serial upvotes are reversed.

---

It seems that new badges will be awarded. Doesn't this open the system for badge abuse, though?  Any master puppeteer could use one of his socks to upvote all his answers that have a score of 9 (or 24, or accepted with 39), with no potential repercussions.

Answer (score 3):

> any Nice Answer or Enlightened badges I earn genuinely, up to those amounts, will not be counted.

As far as I understand the [major change in badge behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96779/badge-behavior-how-should-awarding-work) back in July means you *will* get the badges anyway.

So be happy with what you got! :)

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127380) as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out to me, I didn't know the behaviour had changed. Still, I have 20 bronze and 10 silver badges that I really shouldn't have. I'd prefer to earn them legitimately, if possible :-)

Comment: @Andy you're too good, lol.. I think the team currently believe that once badge is awarded it's for good and can't be revoked no matter what - but things can change.