# badges does not rollback for all badges

Tags: discussion, bug

I am SO user.

I just saw that if I delete an answer more then 3 upvotes then i got displined badge after geting this badge if i undelete my answer then i got my bounty & badge remains the same.

i have search on meta & i found

[Badges are not removed on roll back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127380/badges-are-not-removed-on-roll-back)

but I think this kind of badge must be revert back. otherwise no use of this. I got this badge in 2 account me & my friend same.

so I know its reproducable bug & not any caching issue.

Comment: this means that they know this bug & still not solving? why?
& they will get back badge manually??? sounds odd..

Comment: Incase if you feel guilty of having this badge even after undeleting it, there is no issue in deleting it again.

Comment: Actually it is not a bug, it is [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. Normally, badges are not revoked.

Comment: No it is not odd, rather called as [**status-bydesign**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-bydesign/info).  If you read the answer in the above comment link `However, if the criteria for a badge no longer exist — e.g. the post it was awarded for is deleted — the next award of that badge is negated.`